# Multiple Linear Regression with a saturation curve

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, linear-model

I have a set of data I'm analyzing in R with 2 explanatory variables (X1 and X2), and one response variable (Y).

```
X1<-c(1,2,2,4,5,8,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,6,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,1,3,4,3,6,5,5,3,2,1)
X2<-c(20,40,50,40,50,50,50,30,10,5,10,20,10,10,10,10,50,80,20,10,20,40,40,40,5,20,30,40,50,60,20,20,10,20,10)
Y<-c(70,140,200,240,250,250,250,230,160,105,60,20,60,110,160,210,250,250,250,210,170,140,90,40,55,120,180,240,250,250,250,220,160,120,60)

MyData<-data.frame(X1,X2,Y)
```

My goal is to calculate an equation that will allow me to predict Y based on future X1 and Y1 values. In the past I have used a linear regression like so:

```
MyFit<-lm(Y~X1+X2,data=MyData)
```

And then use this formula to predict Y

```
Y= coefficients(MyFit)[1]+coefficients(MyFit)[2]*X1+coefficients(MyFit)[3]*X2
```

In the above dummy set, Y is strongly driven by X1. But the issue with my real data is that at some point Y gets saturated, so that further increases in X1 do not bring about increases in Y (for this data the saturation value is 250, but the actual values begin to slow down and form a saturation curve as it approaches peak value, as opposed to an absolute saturation point). The result is that the linear model will always over-predict the peak Y values. This can be seen in a plot here:

```
plot(Y,type="l",ylim=c(0,350))
lines(X1,col='red')
lines(X2,col='blue')
lines(coefficients(MyFit)[1]+coefficients(MyFit)[2]*X1+coefficients(MyFit)[3]*X2,col='green')
```

How can I correct for this. Is it possible to do a multiple non-linear regression for this data? Or is there some other technique I can use here?

Comment: A side note: Instead of `Y= coefficients(MyFit)[1]+coefficients(MyFit)[2]*X1+coefficients(MyFit)[3]*X2` simply use `predict(object = MyFit)`

Comment: If you've some theory to suggest an asymptote - rather than a mere tailing off - it could be worth looking at simple non-linear models.

Comment: What are `y`, `x1` and `x2`?

Comment: The above is dummy data that approximates an issue I'm having with an actual data set. So in this case Y is my response variable (Photosynthetic output), and X1 (Light) and X2 (wind) would be my explanatory variables.

Comment: Then [theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PI_curve) & your dummy data concur in suggesting a hyperbolic growth curve for the relationship between photosynthetic rate & light intensity mightn't be a bad model. Wind, up to a point, presumably aids photosynthesis by increasing transpiration, but does it affect the saturated rate or the half-saturation constant, or both? You also need to think about the error structure - is variability in rate roughly the same after light & wind are accounted for? It'd be a good idea to include additional information in your question rather than in comments.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion I caused with my last comment. My data actually has very little to do with photosynthesis, I was just using it as an example. My data is from a marine system, but I thought a terrestrial analog would make more sense to most readers.